# Django - access class attributes of a class-based view in middleware

Tags: python, django, middleware, django-generic-views

I have a couple of views and each of them must be accesed by no more than one user at a time. Therefore I use a locking service for this. My idea is as follows:

### - Declare each view like this

```
class DummyView(View):
    lock = Lock()
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

### - In a middleware, do something like this

```
class Middleware:
    ...
    def __call__(self, request):
        # lock = view.get_lock_if_it_has_one (this is what I need help with)
        lock.acquire()

        response = self.get_response(request)

        lock.release()
        return response
```

How can I access the lock attribute of the view as described?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if you can access a view inside the middleware, so I am just suggesting something more simple and easy to implement / understand.

Simply create a model `Lock` which would have the fields `view_name` (char field), `user` (foreign key) & `is_acquired` (bool). Then, when you want to lock the view for a given request.user (check for anonymous users), simply instantiate the `Lock` model with the `user` & `view_name`, then do a `.acquire()` which basically changes `is_acquired` to `True` (and saves).

And when you want to check if a lock has been acquired, simply check if the given entry `.exists()`.

If you want, you can run a periodic task that expires old locks.

Comment: I would like not to repeat the same code all the time in dispatch method of the views. But yes, when everything else fails, I will use this. Thanks.

Comment: If you are able to access the view inside the middleware, then sure, the repetition is not needed (you can handle it in the middleware), but if not, I don't see a better way.

Comment: You can access it in the middleware -https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#process-view

Comment: I got it, `view_func.view_class`. Thanks.